# problem in estimating Rolling Value at Risk

Tags: stata, var, rolling-computation

I am getting error in Stata by using the following commands:

```
gen daily=date( Date,"MDY")
tsset daily
rolling cent=r(c_1), window(#) clear: centile lnreturn, centile(5)
```

but this is not giving me the result.

Comment: The use of `#` would be an error. Otherwise what is the  precise problem? We need to see a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks legal apart from the use of `#`. Here is a different example that works:

```
webuse grunfeld, clear 

tsset company year

rolling cent=r(c_1), window(7) clear: centile invest, centile(5)
```